# Methods with string parameters and ref in .Net

Tags: .net, il

I have interesting example, could you please explain me it? 
As i understand string is a reference class, but it can not be modified. So when i try to modify string - framework create new reference to new heap address. Bu i do not understand why this new address from method Bear do not pass outside to the main call stack.

```
class DoWork
{
    public static void Beer(string s1)  {
        s1 = s1 + "beer";
    }
    public static void Vodka(ref string s2) {
        s2 = s2 + "vodka";
    }
}

string sss = "I Like ";
DoWork.Beer(sss);
DoWork.Vodka(ref sss);
```

so sss will have value "I Like vodka" but why?

P.S.
or this way

```
DoWork.Vodka(ref sss);
DoWork.Beer(sss);
```

P.P.S. some IL code from example

```
DoWork.Beer:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldstr       "beer"
IL_0006:  call        System.String.Concat
IL_000B:  starg.s     00 
IL_000D:  ret

DoWork.Vodka:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldind.ref   
IL_0003:  ldstr       "vodka"
IL_0008:  call        System.String.Concat
IL_000D:  stind.ref   
IL_000E:  ret
```

Comment: Try this: `string foo = sss; DoWork.Vodka(ref sss)`. Compare foo with sss.

Comment: OT : "bear" is an animal. "beer" is beverage.

Comment: Whether you know it or not, this is essentially a question of "How does `ref` work for reference types?" You'll find the answer to that (and anything else you ever wanted to know) by reading this article by our own Jon Skeet: [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html). It's also helpful to understand the difference between reference and value types, and [Jon's got you covered there as well](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/references.html).

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, `ref` keyword enables the called method to manipulate the reference at the call site. This is the full purpose of `ref`.

What happens is that when `Vodka` returns, `sss` has been replaced with *a new string instance*. It does not update the original instance. Without the `ref` modifier this is not possible.

One thing that I often find that people are confused about when talking about this is when you consider the concepts of passing parameters *by value* and *by reference*, when you deal with *reference types*. When you pass a string (a reference type) *by value*, what is it really that you pass along? You pass the value of the variable. In this case, the value is a reference to a string. So you pass that value, and the calling method can use that value to access the string. However, since the parameter is passed by value, it is the value as such that is passed (essentially a copy of the reference), not the pointer to the memory location storing the value. This is why the calling method cannot replace the instance at the call site.

When passing a parameter *by reference*, instead of the value, the called method gets access to the memory location in which the value is stored (keep in mind now that the value is the reference to the string). This means that the called method can now update this value, to have the variable at the call site contain a reference to another string.

**Update**
Let's dissect the example from your comment (the names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
class SomeClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

class DoWork
{
    public static void DoOne(SomeClass c) { c.Value = c.Value + 1; }
    public static void DoTwo(ref SomeClass c) { c.Value = c.Value + 2; }
}
```

`SomeClass` is a reference type. This means that any piece of code to which you pass such an instance (and, just to be clear, we never pass the actual instance of a reference type, we pass *a reference* to an instance), can manipulate data in that instance*. This means that it can call methods, set property values and so on, and any change in state that this leads to is also visible at the call site. The `ref` keyword has no effect on that. So in your sample, the `ref` keyword makes no difference. However, consider this change:

```
class DoWork
{
    public static void DoOne(SomeClass c) 
    { 
        c = new SomeClass(); 
        c.Value = 1; 
    }
    public static void DoTwo(ref SomeClass c) 
    {
        c = new SomeClass(); 
        c.Value = 2; 
    }
}
```

Now, lets call it:

```
var temp = new SomeClass() { Value = 42 };
DoWork.DoOne(temp);
Console.WriteLine(temp.Value); // prints 42

DoWork.DoTwo(ref temp);
Console.WriteLine(temp.Value); // prints 2
```

What happens now is that both methods create a new `SomeClass` instance to operate on. Since `DoOne` gets the reference passed by value, it will update its own private copy of the reference to point to the new instance, and naturally this change is not seen at the call site.

On the other hand, since `DoTwo` gets the reference passed *by reference*, when it creates a new instance and assigns it to `c`, it updates the same memory location as call site is using, so `temp` is now referencing the new instance created inside `DoTwo`.

To summarize: for reference types, the only time you need to use `ref` is when you want to enable the called method to *replace the passed instance itself*. If you only want to manipulate the state of that instance, reference types will always allow that.

Cody Gray posted a link to Jon Skeet's [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html), if you didn't already, go read it. It does a very good job at explaining these things (and more; it also deals with value types).

*<sub>(unless the type is immutable, like string, but that is a completely different story...)</sub>

Comment: string is reference type and you always work with address to heap
(in local stack you got address to heap)

Comment: @t34: I kept my answer a bit short to focus on the behavior, but of course `sss` does not contain a *string instance*, but *a reference* to a string instance. After all, it is a reference type. Don't get too hung up on the stack vs. the heap in this case though. While it is true in the current implementation of .NET, as Eric Lippert has pointed out [it's an implementation detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) that may or may not change in the future.

Comment: but could you please explain me this example with another reference type 
class class1{public int value;}

class DoWork
{
public static void DoOne(class1 c) { c.value = c.value + 1; }
public static void DoTwo(ref class1 c) {  c.value = c.value + 2; }
}

Comment: GREAT ANSWER
it is very interesting to read
your links are very usefull and i am reading it now, but i've posted a lot of examples just to support our discussion

Answer (score 2):

in `Beer` the pointer to the string is passed by value, so when you do `s1 = s1 + "beer";` the copy of the pointer is changed and it is not visible outside the method.
in `Vodka` however, the pointer to the string is passed by reference, so when you do `s1 = s1 + "vodka";` the same pointer is being changed and it is visible outside the method.

Comment: yes, of course POINTER
it is easy to forget about it in .Net stack, BUT string is reference type and no any difference between methods with ref and without
is not it?

Comment: There is a huge difference between parameters passed by reference or not (the fact that the parameter it self is a reference type does not matter). If you are coming from a c/c++ background you can think of it as the difference between a parameter of type `char *` and `char *&`.

Comment: as i know there is not any pointers in .Net, only reference or value type exists. Am i right?

Comment: What I said is that you can think of it as pointer. And, there are pointers in .Net, search for the `unsafe` keyword if you want to read more about pointers in .Net.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at immutable types

http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them

Comment: There are two things here, the ref keyword and immutability, in the "beer" method, immutability was in effect meaning a new string object was created, the "sss" variable still retained it's old value. The ref keyword caused the vodka method to assign the newly created string object back the "sss" variable

Comment: yes, i am agree with you, because of ref keyword new address of new string variable "i like vodka" push back to the calling stack
without ref - new variable "i like beer" only stored in local stack of Beer function

Comment: but could you explain me this example
class class1{ public int value;}
class DoWork{public static void DoOne(class1 c) {c = new class1(){value = c.value + 1}; }
public static void DoTwo(ref class1 c){c = new class1(){value = c.value + 2};}
}

Comment: The code above does not compile, looks like anonymous inner classes, but c# does not support that.